# C Handling Large Inputs

Tags: c, bignum, uint64

I have seen many questions for this in C++ section. And the most of them suggested using `uint64_t, unsigned long long` and i have tried

- long long
- unsigned long long
- uint64_t

I am giving input of 10^18 as its max input.
But the number being processed is returned as some garbage values.

I am giving it input as `111111111111111110`,
And at the line when I divide it by `10^(step-1)`and multiply it by `10^(step-1)`
The value seems to be oscillating at

```
Right Now In 111111111111111103
Right Now In 111111111111111104 //But it should be 111111111111111100 and then -- to decreas one more
```

This approach works well with lesser values. But not working with greater inputs

[live demo](http://ideone.com/I28Z46)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdint.h>
#include<inttypes.h>
int step = 0;

bool isTidy(uint64_t n){
    step++;
    if(n < 10) return true;
    int lastNumber = n % 10;
    int secondLastNumber = ((n - lastNumber)/10) % 10; 
    return (lastNumber >= secondLastNumber) && isTidy((n - lastNumber)/10);
}

int main(){
    char* inputString;
    uint64_t testNumber;
    int numberOfTestcases;
    int iterator = 1;

    scanf("%d", &numberOfTestcases);
    while(numberOfTestcases --> 0){
        scanf("%"SCNu64,&testNumber);
        do{
            step = 0;
            if(isTidy(testNumber)){
                printf("Case #%d: %"PRIu64"\n",iterator++, testNumber);
                break;
            }
            printf("Right Now In %"PRIu64"\n",testNumber);
            testNumber /= pow(10,step - 1);
            testNumber *= pow(10,step - 1);

            printf("Right Now In %"PRIu64"\n",testNumber);
        }while(testNumber --> 0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

edits: Tried to clear up the question. And fixed the scan input problem

Comment: Posted code will not compile, and generates many warnings.

Comment: @DavidBowling if using gcc then pass -lm too. And see the ideone. its compiling.

Comment: Oops. I missed some headers in copy-paste. Still, there are many, many warnings. You should pay attention to these.

Comment: `testNumber /= pow(10,step - 1);` Do you expect pow to deliver 64 bits exact numbers, after conversion from double to long long?

Comment: @wildplasser its just there to replace the last few digits to zero,

Comment: @DavidBowling but i am not getting any warnings in here in my gcc.

Comment: `%"PRIu64,"\n"` --> `%"PRIu64"\n"`

Comment: that was a typo in my part. I am sorry for that.

Comment: So, the output values are oscillating. What do you expect them to do? Maybe you can **show your expected output**, or otherwise **specify what your program should do**.

Comment: @anatolyg i am dividing it by 10^(step-1) and again multipyling it by 10^(step-1) , so it makes last step-1 digit 0, then doing a --, so the value should become in last step-1 to all 9's. But thats not whats happening here

Comment: **step-1 to all 9's** - that means, do you expect `Right Now In 111111111111111103` and then `Right Now In 456789999999999999` if step=5? You might want to [edit] your post to specify *explicitly* what your expected output is and clarify this.

Comment: @KishanKumar: No, you're not dividing it by 10**(step-1) and then multiplying by 10**(step-1). The value you use is the closest approximation to that the `double` type can support, truncated to an integer. You just cannot use `pow()` here, because it does not have enough precision (typically just 53 bits of mantissa, or just under 16 decimal digits); you must calculate the power of ten you need using integers only -- no intermediate `double` values.

Comment: @anatolyg Thanks for your response. I got the solution from Mikael Mello

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the wrong conversion specifier in the second `scanf()`. You should have:

```
scanf("%"SCNu64,&testNumber);
```

Also, there is a stray comma in one of the `printf()` statements:

```
printf("Right Now In %"PRIu64"\n",testNumber);
```

It is good to enable compiler warnings to help catch such simple errors. I always compile with at least:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic
```

The posted code will compile without warnings if no warnings are enabled.

The additional problem with large inputs can be traced to the `pow()` function, which returns a `double`, not a `uint64_t`. One solution is to replace the calls to `pow()` with calls to another function that returns `uint64_t`. Here is an example, though this is not the most efficient implementation by a long stretch:

```
uint64_t mypow(uint64_t base, unsigned exp)
{
    uint64_t res = 1;

    while (exp--) {
        res *= base;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: still thats not helping me in here. As you can see in ideone, still large number is not being handled.

Comment: @KishanKumar This happens because your solution to the problem is wrong. If you want I can help you with the problem, just not here.

Comment: @MikaelMello yes i would like to get your help. And this approach is correctly working for lesser values.

Comment: @KishanKumar I believe the main problem you are having is because of pow(), it returns a double and a lot of precision is lost with such large numbers. If you use your own pow function (http://ideone.com/lU3XcD), it works fine.

Comment: @MikaelMello thanks.So this one function costed me 15 points and lots of frustration yesterday.

Comment: @MikaelMello-- I was adding such a function to my answer as you left the last comment :)

Comment: @KishanKumar No problem, see you on round 1A! Good luck

Comment: @MikaelMello I forfieted after this one's frustration. Not a place to talk about these.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you are using PRIu64.

I've finished this problem from Google CodeJam and a simple scanf("%lld"), using long long, was sufficient.

---

**Edits**

1. Since my answer apparently wasn't good enough, here are some clarifications, you are getting garbage value while printing because of line 32:

   ```
   printf("Right Now In %"PRIu64,"\n",testNumber);
   ```

   there is a comma after PRIu64, remove that and all values will be printed correctly. Provided you don't get RTE for other reasons (such as an infinity loop).
2. Regarding the problem of the code (from Google CodeJam), it is not working with large numbers (and a infinity loop in your example) because pow() is a double and a lot of precision is lost with large numbers, [if you use your own simple pow() function](http://ideone.com/lU3XcD), you will get an AC.

Comment: @Mikael Mello I also tried long long for large inputs. And it  didn't work on my machine..

Comment: @DavidBowling What is the question then? Because from what I can understand he's asking for a way to read numbers up to 10^18.

Comment: @MikaelMello and i have given a version using uint64_t(which is alias for unsigned long long int)  in the post which is not handling it

Comment: @DavidBowling I agree I missed the point, but to be fair there isn't a question in the post. I will try and answer that then.

Comment: It isn't as clear as it could be, but the question appears to be about why OP is getting garbage values. Not my DV, BTW.

Comment: @DavidBowling Mikael Mello i will try to clear the question, as much possible from me.

Comment: @DavidBowling My interpretation was that he simply wanted a way to properly read large numbers, I didn't know PRIu64 so I just recommended to use a normal long long (because it worked for me in this very problem), didn't even properly read the code and understood the problem. My bad

Comment: @DavidBowling i tried your solutions and edited the ideone. Still the same behaviour,